# Is this a correct way of understanding the third law of thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

The third law of thermodynamics can be stated as:

$$\lim_{T \to 0 \ \mathrm{K}}S = 0 $$

Now, from statistical mechanics: $S = k_B \log W $ where $W$ is the number of microstates. Notice that if $W=1$, then $S=0$. In other words, is the third law a consequence of the fact that systems tend to a single microstate as temperature drops to $0$?

Comment: Perhaps absolute zero would imply zero kinetic energy of particles (no motion at all) so the system could not change its microstate.

Comment: @AVS temperature zero does not correspond in general to zero kinetic energy. First of all, because of quantum mechanics, dominant close to $T=0$, which allows for the zero-point kinetic energy.  Moreover, there are thermodynamic systems, like radiation, where the concept of particles with some kinetic energy becomes meaningless.

Answer (score 8):

[Nernst's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics)  is usually expressed as stating that as $T\to 0$ the entropy of the system approaches a constant. This is more like saying that the heat capacity goes to zero and is more general than just saying that $S(T=0)=0$ because the former also includes the ground state degeneracies, see the wikipedia article for such examples.

Answer (score 6):

The most general statement of the third law is that as $T \rightarrow 0$, system's entropy approaches a unique value, independently of the value of any other thermodynamic variable. Since thermodynamic entropy is defined within an additive constant, it is always possible to put
$$
S(T=0)=0.
$$

Apparently, the microcanonical formula from Statistical Mechanics:
$$
S= k_B \log W,\tag{1}
$$
where $W$ is the number of microstates compatible with a given macrostate at fixed energy, volume, and number of moles would imply the non-degeneracy of the ground state once we translate the limit for vanishing temperature into the limit for energy approaching the ground state.

However, such a conclusion is not consistent with the fact that formula $(1)$, as all the similar formulae of statistical mechanics, does correspond to the thermodynamic entropy only *at the thermodynamic limit*, i.e., in the limit of a large system. Indeed, a degenerate ground state may be compatible with equation $(1)$ and with the third law, provided the degeneracy of the ground state does not grow with the system size so fast to give a contribution to the entropy per particle (or per volume).

Therefore, the correct statement should be *the third law is a consequence of the fact that systems tend to a ground state whose degeneracy $g$ is sub-extensive as temperature drops to zero*. Formally, we have to require that
$$
\lim_{T \rightarrow 0^{+}} g(E,V,N)/V=0
$$
whenever $E,V,N$ go to infinity by keeping constant their ratios. That is a milder condition than the non-degeneracy of the ground state.

Comment: Could you provide a good reference for the last part of your answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @TobiasFünke The first reference I recall saying something explicitly on such an issue is Di Castro and Raimondi "Statistical Mechanics and Applications in Condensed Matter" Cambridge University Press, 2015, section 4.2. However, I think that knowing what to look for, similar observations should be around also elsewhere.